# LEFT JOIN doesn't work

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to write a SQL query, which join three tables.

The tables are:

- `Hotels`: id | name | nz | photo | price | standard | idcountry
- `Countries`: id | name
- `home_promo`: id | idhotel

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    h.id, h.name, h.nz, h.photo, h.price, h.standard,
    h.idcountry, k.name as k_name 
FROM hotels as h 
LEFT JOIN coutries AS k ON k.id=h.idcountry 
LEFT JOIN home_promo AS hm ON hm.idhotel=h.id 
WHERE h.publications=1
```

But it returns all records from hotels table.
Can someone help, please?

Comment: Which results were you expecting?

Comment: All records in the `hotels` table must have a value of `1` in `publications`.  That said, you don't even mention that column when you describe the tables.

Comment: Only those hotel-ids, which are in `home_promo`

Comment: LEFT JOIN -> INNER JOIN between home_promo and hotel tables

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is an outer join so it'll return results even if there's no record there (the `home_promo` fields will be null). You want just `JOIN`

Comment: Perhaps for all hotels in the hotels table the publications field is set to 1. Without seeing some sample data and expected outcome, it is difficult to tell what may cause a query not to return the expected results.

Comment: Almost all records in the hotels have value of 1 in publications.

Comment: Joe Taras - it's working, that is a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Only those hotel-ids, which are in home_promo, then,

```
SELECT h.id,h.name,h.nz,h.photo,h.price,h.standard,h.idcountry,k.name as k_name
FROM hotel_promo hp
LEFT JOIN hotel h on h.id = hp.idhotel
LEFT JOIN coutries AS k ON k.id=h.idcountry
WHERE h.publications=1
```

Comment: I also need names o countries from coutries table. But problem already solved. Joe Taras has given solution.

Comment: I updated my answer, for readibility and easy understanding i would recommend to start the selection from hotel_promo not hotel, as you just said that "Only those hotel-ids, which are in home_promo". Inner join, course gets only matching rows from 2 tables. But your question was about left join.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT h.id,h.name,h.nz,h.photo,h.price,h.standard,h.idcountry,k.name as k_name 
FROM hotels as h 
JOIN home_promo AS hm ON hm.idhotel=h.id 
LEFT JOIN coutries AS k ON k.id=h.idcountry 
WHERE h.publications=1
```

Though maybe you want to remove the LEFT from the countries join too as leaving it there will still return results from hotels with no matching countries.

Answer (score 0):

this query would work if id in home_promo and countries get matched

```
SELECT h.id,h.name,h.nz,h.photo,h.price,h.standard,h.idcountry,k.name as k_name 
FROM hotels as h 
LEFT JOIN coutries AS k ON h.idcountry = k.id 
LEFT JOIN home_promo AS hm ON h.id = hm.idhotel
WHERE h.publications=1
```